C# code not working if there is any space in the file name
I try to execute powershell script with arguments, as below:
string MyBatchFile = @"C:\Test\test.ps1";
String Arg2 = "test7 Test8.SQL";
string Arg1 = "-ReplaceValue";

ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();

psi.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\" \"{2}\" \"", MyBatchFile, Arg1, Arg2);

psi.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" ;

Process.Start(psi);

Here in this Arg2 if specify any file name which has space as shown above "test7 Test8.SQL" , it's not working.
If I provide any filename without space like "Test8.sql" then it works fine.
I would appreciate any input here please.

You need an argument list : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.argumentlist?view=net-8.0#system-diagnostics-processstartinfo-argumentlist

Also in general files names in spaces need to be enclosed in quotes because in CLI tools a space is usually a delimiter (separates arguments) - so Test7 Test8.SQL looks to your command line like two arguments, not one (btw, usually filenames can be enclosed in quotes even if they don't contain spaces, too).

Hmmm I see ... maybe the batch file/script is not handling arguments well either ... weird. Usually I would expected quoted filenames to be okay, :(

There seems to be an extra " at the end of your Arguments

Have you tried initializing an ArgumentList on your ProcessStartInfo? If you read the docs on an ArgumentList it says that it "Gets a collection of command-line arguments to use when starting the application. Strings added to the list don't need to be previously escaped.".
string MyBatchFile = @"C:\Test\test.ps1";
String Arg2 = "test7 Test8.SQL";
string Arg1 = "-ReplaceValue";

ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    ArgumentList =
    {
        MyBatchFile, Arg1, Arg2 
    },
};

// rest of the code

In powershell directly, you would use quotes to delimitate the arguments with spaces so they don't appear as more than one argument. ex: powershell.exe -File "C:\Test\test.ps1" -ReplaceValue "test7 Test8.SQL"

You need to use apostrophes ' instead of double quote " around the parameters passed to powershell script, like this:
string MyBatchFile = @"C:\Test\test.ps1";
String Arg2 = "test7 Test8.SQL";
string Arg1 = "-ReplaceValue";

ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();

psi.Arguments = string.Format("{0} '{1}' '{2}'", MyBatchFile, Arg1, Arg2);

psi.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" ;

Process.Start(psi);

